# Using .htaccess to remove folder from URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I have a Laravel app, and the document root of host is configured at Laravel root folder (upper directory of public).

I tried the following `.htaccess` to silently rewrite URLs, but it keeps redirecting me to /public, instead of showing domain URL and rewriting it to /public

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /public$1 [L,NC]
```

I want to visit `example.com` and see my Laravel app, not redirecting user to `example.com/public`.

Comment: what is your operating system ? linux ? wamp on windows ? give more details

Comment: rather than using .htaccess to change your URLs, why don't you just use routing to achieve the URLs you want?

Comment: It is Linux+Apache. @JamesSpence Can you explain more? I can't understand

Comment: do you have access to terminal ?  via ssh ?

Comment: No. Think of it as a shared hosting.

Comment: @thelastblack Check [this link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This will help you definitely** 
: Removing the /public segment in a Laravel 4 app

http://creolab.hr/2013/03/removing-the-public-segment-in-a-laravel-4-app/

Comment: I already said that VirtualHost is configured and I have no access to that

Comment: ohhh I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

Create a front controller in the document root, call it index.php. Use this front controller to invoke the front controller in the public folder. Make sure you add the .htaccess to that document root prohibiting all sensitive data from being accessed.

Comment: I added `index.php` to root folder with content `require ('public/index.php')`, but images and other assets are not loaded. I think I need extra `.htaccess` rewrite rules for it.